# "Error in if (nvar != dim(rx)[1]) { : argument is of length zero" when trying to run a Scree Plot in R

Tags: r

Currently trying to run a scree plot for a set of data and keep running into an error.

Here is my R code:

```
> library(psych)
> 
> evsmoke <- eigen(cor(smoke_data)) # get eigenvalues
> evsmoke
eigen() decomposition
$values
[1] 5.0235537 1.1024931 0.5978259 0.3411405 0.3084539 0.2482748 0.2253735 0.1528846

$vectors
           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4]        [,5]        [,6]        [,7]         [,8]
[1,]  0.3931577 -0.16571231 -0.3101335  0.2912494  0.23589165  0.05351944 -0.08054941  0.756280417
[2,] -0.3675943  0.25180984  0.4769817 -0.3396868 -0.06445788  0.02456049  0.26511873  0.619291236
[3,]  0.3717502 -0.17776988 -0.2234155 -0.7215427  0.03670089 -0.45944142  0.21731298 -0.001743783
[4,] -0.3011176 -0.57722629  0.1481459 -0.2600885  0.60141194  0.24581963 -0.25052988 -0.040693118
[5,]  0.3859358 -0.12245986  0.1306553 -0.3278663 -0.46591989  0.66115072 -0.23798028  0.025569550
[6,] -0.2555107 -0.70373118 -0.0434621  0.2033157 -0.51156603 -0.11401564  0.33783711  0.086123137
[7,]  0.3419065 -0.17517469  0.6915554  0.1796762 -0.05691227 -0.45195408 -0.36646867  0.008973832
[8,]  0.3876844 -0.05847006  0.3274681  0.1743551  0.30844266  0.26577512  0.71285755 -0.186300292

> evsmoke$values
[1] 5.0235537 1.1024931 0.5978259 0.3411405 0.3084539 0.2482748 0.2253735 0.1528846
> 
> scree(evsmoke, pc=FALSE)  
Error in if (nvar != dim(rx)[1]) { : argument is of length zero
```

What can I do to fix this error?

I expected a Scree plot to be formed but the error message is not allowing me to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `psych::scree()` says the following about the first argument `rx`:

> **rx** a correlation matrix or a data matrix. If data, then correlations are found using pairwise deletions.

Based on the code you provide, I recommend to try `rx = cor(smoke_data)`.

*Example*

```r
library(psych)
data("attitude")
scree(rx = cor(attitude), pc = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>